# Restrict access of admin uploads to certain logged-in users?

Tags: users, uploads, htaccess, user-access

This is a very open-ended, speculative question with lots of possible angles: has anyone worked with ways to restrict the access of certain uploads to a logged in user?

I.e., how can the site admin upload files and assign permissions to each one for certain logged-in users?

Could this entail an uploads directory called /this_user/ in wp-content/uploads/? And restrict access to that with .htaccess and is_logged_in? Or some kind of meta or custom field that assigns permissions and users for uploads?

Other answers here on WPAnswers deal with hotlinking protection, which is a different situation; I need to restrict to logged in users, all on the same domain.

Any ideas?  Thanks

Comment: do you perhaps mean downloads instead of uploads? Site-admin uploads files that become available for download for certain logged-in users?

Comment: Yes; in WordPress nomenclature, uploads - like documents - are also available for download by users and can be called downloads, too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `current_user_has_role` for this

And if the standard roles are not enough for you, then I would suggest to download the Members plugin by Justin Tadlock which enables you to add roles.

Comment: I need to restrict certain uploads to certain users, not all uploads to some users.

Comment: and that is why I said that you could download the Members plugin. With that plugin you create a new role and you give that role to "certain users"